# How do I fix an inconsistent linkage error in flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, localization, sdk

I was excited to find out that Adobe released the data visualization for free so I can use the fancy charts and all with my projects even though I don't have Flex Builder Professional. So I installed the new 3.4 sdk along with the data visualizations. Most all of my projects did fine except for one. This particular project uses localizations. Are there any new compiler arguments that I need to include? I current have -source-path=locale/{locale} -allow-source-path-overlap=true. I get the inconsistent linkage error below:

> Inconsistant linkage in /Applications/Adobe Flex Builder 3/sdks/3.4.0/frameworks/locale/en_US/datavisualization_rb.swc$locale/en_US/core.properties - 'en_US$core_properties' is marked as extern, but 'en_USGBC$core_properties' is not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The one thing I tried is remove the -locale compiler argument and it seemed to work. I don't know for sure if that is the correct way to fix it however.

Comment: when did adobe release the data visualization components for free?

Comment: They didn't according to this: http://blogs.adobe.com/flex/archives/2009/08/status_of_flex_data_visualizat.html

Comment: I think they did. Because here is where they tell you how to install it. http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flex/3/releasenotes_flex3_sdk.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use -locale en_US